# SPI Digital Potentiometer not working on ESP32

Tags: spi, esp32

I have an [MCP4151](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Components/General%20IC/22060b.pdf) digital potentiometer chip. I have managed to get it to work using and Arduino Uno using the code below:

```
#include <SPI.h>

byte address = 0x00;
int CS= 5;

void setup()
{
  pinMode (CS, OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 128; i++)
  {
    digitalPotWrite(i);
    delay(10);
  }
  delay(500);
  for (int i = 128; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    digitalPotWrite(i);
    delay(10);
  }
}

int digitalPotWrite(int value)
{
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(address);
  SPI.transfer(value);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}
```

But when I try to get it to work using an ESP32 programmed using Arduino language it doesn't. I have connected like that

- SCK -> 18
- MOSI -> 23
- SS -> 5

I also used the potentiometer inside like a voltage divider for test purposes. GND on one leg, 3.3v on the other and an LED on the wiper. Are there other settings that I have to implement in order the ESP32 SPI to work like an Arduino SPI? Did I miss something?

Comment: If I am using the SPI defaults (Serial.begin()) and print the variables on the serial monitor Serial.println(MOSI); Serial.println(SCK); Serial.println(SS); I got these defaults MOSI 23, SCLK 18 and SS 5 (VSPI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work in a strange way. I opened the example included in the ESP32 SPI Library and copied some points from there.

I first initialise a pointer to the SPI class, then I call **`begin()`** at that pointer and inside the `digitalPotWrite` function I call **`beginTransaction(10000,MSBFIRST,SPI_MODE0)`** and end the transaction before `digitalPotWrite` finishes. Full code here:

```
#include <SPI.h>

static const int spiClk = 1000000;
byte address = 0x00;
SPIClass * hspi = NULL;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
  hspi = new SPIClass(HSPI);
  hspi->begin(); 
}

void loop()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 128; i++)
  {
    digitalPotWrite(i);
    delay(10);
  }
  delay(500);
  for (int i = 128; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    digitalPotWrite(i);
    delay(10);
  }
}

int digitalPotWrite(int value)
{
  hspi->beginTransaction(SPISettings(spiClk, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(15, LOW);
  hspi->transfer(address);
  hspi->transfer(value);
  digitalWrite(15, HIGH);
  hspi->endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ESP32 SPI library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/SPI/src/SPI.cpp) has defaults for the HSPI pins (14, 12, 13, 15). For VSPI pins, you must specify the pins in begin().

```
SPI.begin(18, 19, 23, 5);
```

Comment: I both tried to use the HSPI pins with SPI.begin(); and those pins using SPI.begin(18, 19, 23, 5); but nothing worked. Maybe ESP32 used an incompatible frequency for SPI?

Answer (score -1):

Change the int for a void in the function...
That's it.
When you call that function is never going back, still waiting for a return.

```
int digitalPotWrite(int value)
{
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(address);
  SPI.transfer(value);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}
```