# ESP32 SPI communication with MCP3903 not working

Tags: spi, esp32, adc

I am trying to read out the Microchip MCP3903 six channel ADC using an ESP32 via SPI communication. The MCP3903 is powered with 5V and 3,3V and is connected with an external 3,57 MHz crystal. The ESP32 I use is the Olimex ESP32-EVB and the code is uploaded with the Arduino IDE. It works perfectly for other projects, so the ESP seems to be OK.

For the MCP3903 a library exists (https://github.com/mjklopfer/MCP3903) with an example that I am trying to run but nothing is happening. I have tried to use VSPI (GPIO 23, 19,18 and 5) and HSPI (GPIO 13, 12, 14, 15) but I am not getting a CLK signal when I check with the scope. I also tried to alter the code using pointers as suggested here: [SPI Digital Potentiometer not working on ESP32](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55805/spi-digital-potentiometer-not-working-on-esp32), but also that is not changing anything.

You can find the code of the MCP3909 example that I am trying out below. I suppose that when the MCP is not connected, I would still see the CLK running? Is there something special that needs to happen with the GPIOs, like pull-up resistors or something the like? How can I check that the problem is software related or hardware related?

```
/*
mcp3903example.ino
Arduino example for the MCP3903 - Example tested 
Extended from the Arduino Library for MCP3903 A/D Converter
 * MCP3903 Library
 * Kerry D. Wong
 * http://www.kerrywong.com, http://www.kerrywong.com/2014/05/10/mcp3903-library/, https://github.com/kerrydwong/MCP3903) * 5/2014
Minor Arduino Feature extensions by Zhi Luo, Kaixin Chen, Yaxin "Erica" Deng, Yutian Ren, and Michael Klopfer, Ph.D.
University of California, Irvine
2018
*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include "MCP3903.h"


//Set the gains and offsets for your ADC channels:
#define ch0_gain 2.383490972 //these are values for calibration. By setting these values, reads will be the same as the inputs. 
#define ch0_offset -0.007884781 //the maximum read for each channel will be around 0.7866. The deviation for these values is around 2%

#define ch1_gain 2.383490972
#define ch1_offset -0.007884781

#define ch2_gain 2.383490972
#define ch2_offset -0.007884781

#define ch3_gain 2.383490972
#define ch3_offset -0.007884781

#define ch4_gain 2.383490972
#define ch4_offset -0.007884781

#define ch5_gain 2.383490972
#define ch5_offset -0.007884781


MCP3903 mymcp3903;  //Initialize mymcp3903 object for the MCP3903 

void setup()
{
    //esp.begin(); Needed with ESP8266 for ESP class functions
  Serial.begin(9600); //set serial comm at 9600 bps
  SPI.begin(); //Start SPI
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));  //Start SPI transaction with defined parameters 
        mymcp3903.init(10); // (10 for UNO; 15 for esp8266)Setings for your Arduino's/ESP8266's SPI pin used for interfacing(pinCS) - make sure this is the pin you have your CS on!
        mymcp3903.reset(MCP3903::OSR_256); 
        mymcp3903.setGain(1,MCP3903::GAIN_8);
  //Need to initialize all channels to use
  SPI.endTransaction(); //End SPI transaction

}


void loop()
{
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));  //Start SPI transaction with defined parameters 

    
  //Print out the ADC value of channel 0
  Serial.print("Channel 0 ADC Value: "); //Start your line here
    double ch0 = mymcp3903.readADC(0);
    double ch0Cal = (ch0* ch0_gain)+ch0_offset;
    Serial.println(ch0Cal);//Add value then end your line
  delay(10);  //Delay before next Ch read (totally optional)
  
  
  //Print out the ADC value of channel 1
    Serial.print("Channel 1 ADC Value: "); //Start your line here
    double ch1 = mymcp3903.readADC(1);
    double ch1Cal = (ch1* ch1_gain)+ch1_offset;
    Serial.println(ch1Cal);//Add value then end your line
  delay(10);  //Delay before next Ch read (totally optional)
  
  
  //Print out the ADC value of channel 2
    Serial.print("Channel 2 ADC Value: "); //Start your line here
    double ch2 = mymcp3903.readADC(2);
    double ch2Cal = (ch2* ch2_gain)+ch2_offset;
    Serial.println(ch2Cal);//Add value then end your line
  delay(10);  //Delay before next Ch read (totally optional)
  
  //Print out the ADC value of channel 3
  Serial.print("Channel 3 ADC Value: "); //Start your line here
    double ch3 = mymcp3903.readADC(3);
    double ch3Cal = (ch3* ch3_gain)+ch3_offset;
    Serial.println(ch3Cal);//Add value then end your line
  delay(10);  //Delay before next Ch read (totally optional)
  
  //Print out the ADC value of channel 4
  Serial.print("Channel 4 ADC Value: "); //Start your line here
    double ch4 = mymcp3903.readADC(4);
    double ch4Cal = (ch4* ch4_gain)+ch4_offset;
    Serial.println(ch4Cal);//Add value then end your line
  delay(10);  //Delay before next Ch read (totally optional)
  
  //Print out the ADC value of channel 5
  Serial.print("Channel 5 ADC Value: "); //Start your line here
    double ch5 = mymcp3903.readADC(5);
    double ch5Cal = (ch5* ch5_gain)+ch5_offset;
    Serial.println(ch5Cal);//Add value then end your line
  delay(10);  //Delay before next Ch read (totally optional)
  
  
  
    delay(100);  //Delay, then re-run loop to read sensors again
  //SPI.endTransaction(); //End SPI transaction - we are keeping this open for this example
}
```

Comment: I suggest you just reduce your program to using SPI to send a byte repeatedly. Remove the MCP3903 library from the equation.